# How can I generate a UML diagram in VSC from Python code?

Tags: python, uml, reverse-engineering, pylint

When I use pylint for this I get an error message.
I have tried it with **pylint**, see below:

```
py -m pylint --generate-uml -o $Path code.py
```

> **Add I get the following error message:**
> *pylint: error: Unrecognized option found: generate-uml, o,*

I also tried it directly with **[pyreverse](https://I%20also%20tried%20it%20directly%20with%20pyreverse,%20that%20didn%27t%20work%20either,%20although%20the%20part%20is%20from%20pylint)**, that didn't work either.

Comment: Pyreverse is still the best option and anyway VSC doesn't deal with python class diagrams. I'd advise to try harder this option and reinstall it if it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you use chatGPT to get this command ? I would suggest reading the doc instead : https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyreverse.html

Comment: Moreover, can you be more specific about what exactly "didn't work either" with pyreverse ?

Comment: Yes, I had the command from chatgbt. And that was wrong. Indeed, it works with pyreverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[pyreverse](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyreverse.html) does that, the command need to be launched with `pyreverse code.py`. Check the output of `pyreverse --help`for more details.

Comment: Thank you. I have checked it. I was too hasty with the problem. Because I was in the wrong path, it couldn't work.